# A function with a range set, that contains differences of two prime numbers.

Tags: functions, prime-numbers, prime-gaps

I've been asked to give a total and computable function $f:\mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$, with a range set $R_f = B$ with $B$ defined as follows:
 $$B =  \{n \mid \text{there exist two primes }p,q \geq 2 \text{ with } n = p-q\}$$

---

I don't know how to approach the problem. I've been reading about prime gabs of two consecutive primes and there properties but i did't get any idea. $p,q$ don't have to be consecutive but i think n must be a sum of consecutive prime gabs. (e.g. if there is a prime number $s$ between $p$ and $q$, then $n$ will be the sum of  differences $n = (s-q) + (p - s)$).

Please help!

Comment: To confirm, for each $n$, there must exist primes $p,q$ with $f(n)=p-q$. And for all pairs $(p,q)$ of distinct primes, there must exist $n$ with $f(n)=|p-q|$?

Comment: there is no restrictions nor details about the parameter of the function. n is here the difference between the primes and doesn't have to be the parameter.

Comment: i.e. n is here the output. But for each $ x \in \mathbb{N}$ there must be $f(x) = n$ such that, $n = |p - q|$. Hope i answered your question.

Answer (score 0):

Given $n$, let $a=\lfloor\sqrt n\rfloor$ and $b=\min\{n-a^2,a\}$. Then $a$ runs through all of $\Bbb N$, and $b$ takes all values in the interval $0\le b\le a$. Let $p$ be the $(b+1)$st prime and $q$ the $(a+2)$nd prime. Finally, let $f(n)=q-p$.

Comment: Thank you for responding, but i don't understand why you chose this interval to work with? can you please explain a little bit more?